# Theme for LXDE in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, themes, lxde

I saw some old discussions, but I am not sure whether I could make them work. Gnome was using too much memory ( 1.5 GB ) on 18.04, so I tried LXDE ( now 800 MB ). But the file manager windows reminds of *Windows 95*. I can live with that. But I am sure someone has made a theme to improve that. Is there one ? If yes, where can I find it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Lubuntu 18.04, the file manager is PCManFM. Lubuntu's applications in 18.04 are mostly gtk2- and gtk3-based.

Run `apt search theme | grep -i gtk+`. There's a long list for you to choose from. Ensure that the theme you test supports both gtk2 and gtk3. Some themes only support one: in such cases, you'll get ugly looking applications.

Then there are external sources as well but you need to choose wisely because a particular theme may not be suitable for your current system: this mainly affects applications using gtk3 because gtk3 is evolving rapidly.

---

I'll also note that you refer to *LXDE* and not to *Lubuntu* which makes me guess that you did not install *lubuntu-desktop* but something else, more limited.

I suggest you install *lubuntu-desktop* which will provide you with decent appearances for your applications. To do so, run `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`, `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`, in that order, and then log out and log back in making sure to choose *Lubuntu* at your login screen.

Comment: Thanks. I installed default 18.04 with Gnome and then added LXDE. Opting that through login now. How can I choose a theme or icon theme. Is there something like Tweak tool ?

Comment: Even though I mentioned LXDE, I install `lubuntu-desktop` package. It was either through synaptic package manager or some command, I don't remember how.

Comment: Looks like I do not have the " Look and feel " option. But upon further exploration there is `Openbox Configuration Manager` where I can change from a list of available themes.

Comment: I was getting regular popups about " Display Settings ". Unable to work with that. I had to uninstall for now. Thanks for your help.